# Jest test case is getting failed due to special character in Received result

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, jestjs

In below test case for result variable received value is having special character due to that test case is getting failed.

[image]

In Line 40 I have kept debug point and copied the value of result after exeution of line 40 and pasted into notepad++, I am getting below.

[image]

could someone help me out here, suspected area could be some missing settings of vscode editor.